# Как настроить Edit для определённого расширения файла?

Tags: windows, реестр

Например для файлов .txt в контексном меню мы можем увидеть два пункта **Open** и **Edit**.

[image: Элемент Edit контексного меню файла]

Как заданому расширению файла назначить пункт **Edit**, чтобы после нажатия этого пункта файл открывался определённой программой?

Comment: См. [раз](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx) и [два](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#reg_verbs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так.

Согласно [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx), чтобы добавить свой пункт в контекстное меню файла нужно внести параметры по своему обработчику в реестр Windows.
Соответственно, параметры вносятся либо в ветку `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` для всех пользователей, либо в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` для текущего пользователя.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

; Вносим свои параметры для контекстного меню файла
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext\shell]
; Задаём пункт по умолчанию для контекстного меню.
@="doit"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext\shell\doit]
; Задаём название пункта меню.
@="Do It!"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext\shell\doit\command]
; Задаём команду для "Do It!"
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyTM\\MyApplication\\my.exe\" \"%1\""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext\shell\edit]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MyTM.myext\shell\edit\command]
; Задаём команду для редактирование
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe\" \"%1\""

; Вносим расширение в реестор.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.myext]
;Задаём наши параметы как текущие.
@="MyTM.myext"
; Добавляем свои параметры в список возможных параметров для контекстного меню файла.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\.myext\OpenWithProgids]
"MyTM.myext"=""
```

Для более высокой надёжности перегружаем свою учётную запись.

Результат:
[image: Пункты меню]

Но, вы можете и не увидеть своих результатов. Связано это может быть с тем, что параметры для расширения для текущего пользователя пренудительно заданы через "Open with". Т.е. в этом случае пользователь сам назначает, какие параметры использовать и это значение будет хранить в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.htm\UserChoice`.
Что бы изменить это значение можно воспользоваться контекстным меню `Open with->Choose default program...`, удалить его или самим установить:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.myext\UserChoice]
"Progid"="MyTM.myext"
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В реестре прописать расширение в `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`. Например, `.mfile`.
2. Прописать название файла для расширения. Например, `Mytestfile`.
3. Создайте для Mytestfile разделы:

   - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\wmffile\shell\open\command`,
   - `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\wmffile\shell\edit\command`
4. Укажите команду запуска файла: `"Путь к программе" %1`. На место `%1` будет подставляться имя открываемого файлп.

Проще всего посмотрите `.jpeg` и `.mp3` файлы, а также `.doc` для WinWord. Все сразу станет понятно.

Для Word'а нагляднее даже. Вот на моём компьютере путь к разделу: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Document.8\shell\Edit\command`.

Comment: [Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144148(v=vs.85).aspx) написано _"The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT subtree is a view formed by merging HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes"_. Т.е. походу когда пишешь в  HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT то на самом деле пишешь в HKEY_CURRENT_USER?

Comment: Скорее всего да. Можно написать в HKEY_CLASSES, открыть HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes и посмотреть появится ли оно. Если нет, значит в HKLM должно быть.

Comment: @MaLS Строчкой ниже там же написано, что _«In general, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is intended to be read from but not written to.»_ То есть, писать туда настоятельно не рекомендуется.